# Pandas from matrix to DataFrame

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I've a matrix, user-item matrix that I generate from:

```
matrix = df.pivot(index='user', columns='item', values='rating')
```

each row of matrix correspond to a user, each column to an item.
Ordered list of users and items are stored in two lists so that i-th element of users list correspond to the id of i-th user in the i-th matrix's row.

After some processing on that matrix I want to switch back into a DataFrame with tree columns (user, item, rating)

```
   user  item  rating
0     1  1907     4.0
1     1  1028     5.0
2     1   608     4.0
3     1  2692     4.0
4     1  1193     5.0
```

I can't figure out how. Suggestions?

Comment: Here's a suggestion: Post your data and expected output.

Comment: Data + expected output + code you tried so far. If you are interested in asking great questions, take a look here: [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a pivoted dataframe of this format -

```
item  608   1028  1193  1907  2692
user                              
1      4.0   5.0   5.0   4.0   4.0
```

You can `stack` your data and then reset the index -

```
df.stack().reset_index(name='rating')

   user  item  rating
0     1   608     4.0
1     1  1028     5.0
2     1  1193     5.0
3     1  1907     4.0
4     1  2692     4.0
```

Comment: Yeah it works fine. I obtain a df like the following:

        level_0  level_1    rating
0             0        0  5.000000
1             0        1  0.000000
2             0        2  0.000000
3             0        3  0.000000
4             0        4  0.000000

How to map level_0 values to the i-th value of a list?

Comment: @Progeny Sorry, I didn't follow your problem completely. If possible, open a new question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `melt`:

```
df_tab = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='user',value_name='ratings')
```

Output:

```
   user  item  ratings
0     1   608      4.0
1     1  1028      5.0
2     1  1193      5.0
3     1  1907      4.0
4     1  2692      4.0
```

and back to matrix:

```
matrix = df_tab.pivot(index='user', columns='item', values='ratings')
```

Output:

```
item  1028  1193  1907  2692  608
user                             
1      5.0   5.0   4.0   4.0  4.0
```